# Watson IOT Platform dashboard

Tags: metadata, dashboard, watson

I am working on IBM Watson IoT platform. I wish to understand how I can view my meta data attributes  related to ALL devices registered in the platform, on the platform dashboard (not per device or device type)

Answer (score 1):

you can do that : go to you watson iot dashboard ,

1_ go to Boards.

2_ choose one board or create new one ( I recommand the device centric analytics

3_ click on add new card and choose linechart

4_then u ll have to select your devices types that u want to visualise ( select them all in your case )  and then enter data properties name u wish u visualize. u ll see them all in one line chart.

if you want to see them in seperate linecharts on the same board. add different linechart.

If this help u please confirm it by cliking the "green tick"

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that this is not possible at this point in time.

The metadata that is defined at the **Device Type** level is used a template when creating a **Device** of that type.  However, the user has the ability to completely override this metadata at **Device** creation time.  As a result, the metadata on every single device registered with the platform could be unique.  For a single Org, this is a potentially huge number of devices spread across multiple device types.

Providing support for this functionality would be possible, but it is a new requirement.  Please could you raise an enhancement request for this functionality?